# GPUImageMovieWriter - black frame caused by audioEncodingTarget

Tags: gpuimage

I'm trying to record video using the GPUImage library. The recorded clip ends with a black frame. I know that is caused by **audioEncodingTarget** that is a very expensive operation. This has been discussed a lot, but i still don't find a solution.
Here is my code:

**GPUCameraRecorder class init**

```
    videoCamera = GPUImageVideoCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540, cameraPosition: .Back)
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = .LandscapeRight;
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = true

    filter = GPUImageFilter()
    videoCamera.addTarget(filter)

    view = GPUImageView(frame: frame)
    view.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill

    movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: output, size: view.frame.size)
    movieWriter?.encodingLiveVideo = true

    filter?.addTarget(movieWriter!)
    filter?.addTarget(view as GPUImageView)

    videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter!
    videoCamera.startCameraCapture()
```

**start recording function**

```
func startRecording(){
    println("Start recording.")
    recording = true

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        var res = self.videoCamera.addAudioInputsAndOutputs()
        println(res)

        self.movieWriter!.startRecording()            
    }
}
```

**end recording function**

```
func stopRecording(){
    println("Recording end.")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {            
        self.filter?.removeTarget(self.movieWriter!)
        self.videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil
        self.movieWriter!.finishRecording()

        self.putTorchOff()
        self.delegate?.recordingEnd()

        println("completed")
    }
 }
```

Any suggestion? Someone have find a way to make it work without black frames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this ?

Inside GPUImageMovieWriter.m
add code:

```
static BOOL allowWriteAudio = NO;

- (void)startRecording;
{
  ...
  allowWriteAudio = NO;
}

- (void)processAudioBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)audioBuffer;
{
  if (!allowWriteAudio) {
    return;
  }
  ...
}

- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex;
{
  ...
  if (![assetWriterPixelBufferInput appendPixelBuffer:pixel_buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime])
    NSLog(@"Problem appending pixel buffer at time: %@", CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(kCFAllocatorDefault, frameTime)));

  allowWriteAudio = YES;   //< add this
  ...
}
```

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1255

Comment: Still I am getting that black frame